Como Simular una interfaz con Mockito o si existe alguna otra forma?
¿Quizás alguien sabe y puede ayudarme con el simulado que se muestra a continuación?
Quiero hacer un caso de prueba simulando la clase ProcessDateService. Esta por debajo en su implementación usa la Interfaz ConnectionProvider.
Quiero simular la interfaz ConnectionProvider:
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
class ProcessDateServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private ConnectionResolver connectionResolver;
    @Mock
    private ConnectionProvider connectionProvider;
    @Mock
    private Connection connection;
    @Mock
    private Statement statement;
    @Mock
    private ResultSet resultSet;
    @InjectMocks
    private ProcessDateService processDateService;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() throws SQLException {
        when(connectionResolver.getConnectionProvider()).thenReturn(connectionProvider);
        when(connectionProvider.getConnection()).thenReturn(connection);
        when(connection.createStatement()).thenReturn(statement);
        when(statement.executeQuery(anyString())).thenReturn(resultSet);
    }

    @Test
    void getProcessDate_Success_Test() throws SQLException {
        LocalDateTime expectedDate = LocalDateTime.now();
        when(resultSet.next()).thenReturn(true);
        when(resultSet.getTimestamp(1)).thenReturn(java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(expectedDate));

        LocalDateTime processDate = processDateService.getProcessDate();

        assertNotNull(processDate);
        assertEquals(expectedDate, processDate);
    }

Pero me sale el siguiente error:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.cobis.cloud.infra.nativ.db.ConnectionResolver.getConnectionProvider()" because "this.connectionResolver" is null 

utiliza @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class) en lugar de: @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
si tienes problemas verifica las dependencias
ahora eso es para JU5 porque esta la etiqueta de la pregunta.. y @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) es para JU4
usas @BeforeEach que es paa JU5.. porque @Before es para JU4
realmente que es lo que  buscas.. JU4 o JU5 ?
